# Would it be possible to keep a whale alive whilst harvesting its fat?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

Firstly, I’m sorry that this is a rather horrible question to ask!

Would it be possible to keep a whale alive whilst harvesting its fat or blubber? These whales would be living in captivity already and the community keeping them would want to use their fat as a fuel source. However, they would want to keep the whale alive so that it would keep producing fat, which could be harvested on a continuous basis, rather than having to go out and hunt a whale each time they needed more fuel.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Hello, *Twiga-Lil*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  Please take our [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.  Have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. Have fun!

Comment: What are they feeding the whales with and why don't they just use that as the fuel source?

Comment: So basically sustainable whale liposuction.

Comment: @John - that is the answer.  Put it up!

Comment: An excellent world-building related question! A reminder to all VTCers: your Mods have spoken --- *questions regarding real world stuff are on-topic*.

Comment: @Willk I don't know how to make liposuction sustainable, liposuction produces scar tissue so you can't do it over and over. At most your doubling or tripling the fat you get from each whale and you get some before you have to kill it.

Comment: @TimB That one's kinda easy to answer. The whale's food can't be burnt (like plankton) but by feeding the whale, the whale converts non-burnable material into burnable material.

Comment: @elemtilas Actually the community has spoken, the mods are just the voice of the community.

Comment: @SydneySleeper There are still far more efficient ways to do that conversion - biofuels use a number of different methods :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you could liposuction them but why would you? Suddenly you need to feed said whales.

"A blue whale eats up to 3,600 kg (8,000 lb.) of krill each day for about 120 days. It is estimated to take 1,000 kg (2,200 lb.) of food to fill a blue whale's stomach. Gray whales eat about 150,000 kg (340,000 lb) of food during a 130 to 140 day feeding period - a daily average intake of about 1,089 kg (2,400 lb.)."

So suddenly instead of hunting whales, you're fishing even more to try and keep the whales fed.

If you rended down the tonnes and tonnes of krill needed, you'd have more oil than what you can collect from the whale anyway.

The whole point of whale hunting is the whales go get the krill themselves and you only have to get the whale.

Comment: This right here. If whale fat was the only way forward, a real conservation effort around it would be through licensed hunts and ecology preservation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have technology somewhat equivalent to *Star Trek* transporters you could probably find a way to remove fat from the whales without harming them.  There would definately be a limit to how much fat you could take, so you might have to feed the whales a lot so they become very fat - or would if you didn't take away some of their fat.

I remember an old science fiction story where a fat man looked slender because he kept all his fat in a suitcase, kept alive and connected to his body somehow, maybe with wormholes or something. Someone though he must have had a treasure in the suitcase he guarded so carefully and stole it.

Answer (score 0):

You milk the whale. A female whale, obviously. Whale milk is up to [50% fat](https://www.whalefacts.org/whale-milk/). Then you boil the milk (or let it sit in the hot sun) to drive off some of the water and increase the fat content even more.

You still have the problems of feeding the whale, and she'll only produce milk when she has a calf.